# LockWorkStation not working in Powershell through Task Scheduler

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, task-scheduler

I'm writing a script which receive commands from Amazon Echo bridged by IFTTT.

The process goes as follows:

- I ask Alexa to trigger "X"
- IFTTT sends that to Dropbox Applet
- Dropbox writes a text file named "X" in a directory
- A Task Scheduled Powershell script loops every 5 seconds to detect any files in that directory
- Script executes commands based on file name

Here's a short example of the script:

```
$SearchDirectory = "C:\Users\Username\Dropbox\IFTTT"
$SleepTime = 5
$Status = "none"

Remove-Item -Path "$SearchDirectory\shutdown.txt" -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Remove-Item -Path "$SearchDirectory\restart.txt" -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Remove-Item -Path "$SearchDirectory\sleep.txt" -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Remove-Item -Path "$SearchDirectory\lock.txt" -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

While ($True) {
  Do {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds $SleepTime

    if (Test-Path -Path "$SearchDirectory\shutdown.txt") { $Status = "shutdown" }
    if (Test-Path -Path "$SearchDirectory\restart.txt") { $Status = "restart" }
    if (Test-Path -Path "$SearchDirectory\sleep.txt") { $Status = "sleep" }
    if (Test-Path -Path "$SearchDirectory\lock.txt") { $Status = "lock" }
  }
  Until ($Status -ne "none")

  switch ($Status) {
    "shutdown" { Remove-Item -Path "$SearchDirectory\shutdown.txt"; Stop-Computer -Force; break }
    "restart" { Remove-Item -Path "$SearchDirectory\restart.txt"; Restart-Computer -Force; break }
    "sleep" { Remove-Item -Path "$SearchDirectory\sleep.txt"; Suspend-Computer; break}
    "lock" { Remove-Item -Path "$SearchDirectory\lock.txt"; Invoke-Command {rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation}; break}
    "none" { break }
  }

  $Status = "none"
}
```

All of the commands above work fine except for `rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation` which appears to be working OK in the console but not through a script in the Task Scheduler.

I can't see the problem so why is it not working?

Comment: Is the task scheduler script running as current user? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/3f0ade25-acb1-4821-8a78-9384716850ff/creating-scheduled-task-for-currently-logged-on-user?forum=winserverGP

Comment: Yes, it is, and it is also running with the highest privileges on an unrestricted execution policy.